# Nameref variables

Tags: bash

Have been using

```
typeset -n ref="$1"
```

to set a nameref variable within a function.

I think that the command is also equivalent to

```
local -n ref="$1"
```

Which would allow one to change the value of a variable passed to the function for use outside the function.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be much faster to just test this yourself than to write this question?

In your use case both variants are equivalent, indeed. The created variable is local in one case only but the referenced variable is global in both cases (unless you define it as local in that function).

Comment: I did test it actually.  The only thing is that I could not find explanations about what happens if you'd use typeset or declare in a function.

Comment: My understanding is that the  `nameref`  in  `local -n ref="$1"`  effectively changes the meaning of "local" to allow the variable to be modified and retain its value outside of the function. Thus, making the variable "global" within the script.

Comment: @Bennings so you're saying `ref` remains available as a variable outside the function? If not, it still is a local variable.

Comment: If I do `function frank () {local -n ref="$1"; ref=that} ; var=this ; frank var ; echo $var` the second `echo` gives `that`.

Comment: @Bennings `ref` is local, `var` is global. `ref` points to a global variable so the change in the function is global. But there is no variable `ref` outside the function.

Comment: Right, there is no variable `ref` outside the function.  But as you say an assignment to `ref` changed a global variable.  If I want to pass an array to the function, a nameref must be used (using the `-n` option).  Whether one uses `local -n`, `typeset -n`, or `declare -n`.  I do not see a way to avoid using a nameref variable.

Comment: @Bennings The opposite is true: You cannot use `nameref` with an array; at least not up to and inclusing bash 5.2. Quoting the man page: `Array variables cannot be given the nameref attribute.` You can use `eval`, though (as we did before the introduction of `nameref`.

Comment: @Bennings what's preventing your script's function/subroutine from reading and writing the script's global variable directly?

Comment: I am using the nameref feature on arrays on the latest bash version.

Comment: Because I am writing a bash library, I do not want to use specific global named variables.  But allow one to pass  whatever global variable a user wants to update.  The code would then be self-adapting to any global variable a user wants to define.